# Hopping Profile

Tags: hops

I am trying to get a huge IPA hop profile in some of my beers and they are not quite there yet.  Do you guys tend to lean towards massive late addition hops or do you try to add the hop aroma/flavor from dry hops?  Personally, I do a bit of both, but I don't have it dialed in yet.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Is the beer lacking hop bitterness, aroma and/or flavor?

Answer (score 1):

Both. Use lots of hops late edition and a lot dry hopping. All depends on what you want to achieve profile wise. This is a good article on [late hopping](http://www.mrmalty.com/late_hopping.php).

Comment: honestly the last few ive been doing ive been shooting for that New Englandish style, even though its getting old fast....  So I do low bittering charge but then dump a ton of hops into whirlpool and then again into dry hop.  Ive been using a bit of both and going to fruit forward hops such as citra (primarily,) mosaic and a ton of galaxy.   But I still cant get that flavor that I get in other beers.  Im 99% sure that somewhere between an amazing wort and beer something is going wrong... Any tips for pitching or yeast or whatever id appreciate.  Thanks!

Comment: What type of yeast are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you like the flavor profile you're getting and just want more, the answer is probably exactly what you expect: use more hops. Otherwise, you will probably want to experiment w/ varieties. A good start is to find a commercial beer you like, figure out what hops they use and start from there.

I find the most efficient way is to do a bittering addition at the start of the boil and save the rest for the last ten minutes or so plus dry hop. I work from this philosophy for a pretty hefty majority of my beers but being most effecient/cost effective isn't necessarily what will give you the best beer. My very best and biggest hop monsters have been where I've gone all out: first wort hops, additions every ten or fifteen minutes and huge additions at the end of the boil and big piles of dry hops. This is where you are really pushing beyond the point of diminishing returns and are just throwing hops at the issue.

For rough guidelines on amounts, I'd say maybe 2-6 oz at the end of the boil plus at least a couple ounces dry hops.